# When there are multiple expressions that return, how do you unit test where the method returned?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nunit, moq

I would like to unit test my method and make sure that the method returns when **condition1 = true**:

```
public bool condition1{get;set;}
public bool condition2{get;set;}
public void Consume(IConsumeContext<mymessage> context)
{
    if (context.Message==null)
    {
        Logme("No message");
        return;
    }
    if (condition1)
    {
        Logme("condition1 is true");
        return;
    }
    if (condition2)
    {
        Logme("condition2 is true");
        return;
    }
    //do work
}
```

Is there any way to know where exactly the method **Consume** returned?

Comment: short from parsing whatever Logme() outputs there is no way in your current function. You could however change the return type and return a more meaningful value, like an enum?

Comment: @JanR thank you. would the enum be a public property of the class?

Comment: You would be able to tell by the side-effects caused by exiting at the third return rather than the second. If there are no side-effects, then it's probably not useful information for the unit test, I would assume.

Comment: If you need to use the result somewhere then a public enum would be the way to go. but like Rob mentioned in his comment, it depends on the side effects if it will be worth testing in the first place.

Comment: looks like im forced to define this method as void, so i wouldnt be able to return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure.

An unit test is a very targeted piece of test, used to verify a specific scenario. In this case, your scenario definition is that, you want to verify that when Message is not null, and Confition1 is true, your target method returned due to condition1, and not due to Message null or condition2.

By defining the scenario, we have established the pre-conditions for your unit test.

```
IConsumeContext<mymessage> contextMock = new Mock<IConsumeContext<mymessage>>();
contextMock.Setup(c => c.Message).Returns("Not_A_Null_Value");

var obj = new UberConsumer();
obj.Condition1 = true;

// obj.Condition2 doesn't really matter.. so you could run a combination of the tests, 
// one for condition2 = true and another for false.
```

and now the most important part. to verify that your target code returned due to Condition1, you need to do one more thing:

able to verify that this call was indeed made by the target code and was the only call to LogMe.

```
 Logme("condition1 is true");
```

The best way to do that would be to mock this method, or if it is not mockable, abstract it out into an interface and mock it out. and if it is a simple harmless method which just assigns the string to a variable, you could assert that variable. let us assume that it is a mockable method.

so your test would look something like this..

```
// arrange
IConsumeContext<mymessage> contextMock = new Mock<IConsumeContext<mymessage>>();
contextMock.Setup(c => c.Message).Returns("Not_A_Null_Value");

var obj = new UberConsumer();
obj.Condition1 = true;

// obj.Condition2 doesn't really matter.. so you could run a combination of the tests, 
// one for condition2 = true and another for false.

// setup callback for the mockable LogMe method and capture the string parameter value
   // string capturedStringValue = null
   // mockLogMeObj.Setup(l => l.LogMe(It.IsAny<string>()).Callback(val => { capturedStringValue = val} );
   // you could also verify the call count

// act
uberConsume.Consume(contextMock.Object);

// assert

// assert that the captured parameter of Logme was "condition1 is true"
Assert.Equals("condition1 is true", capturedStringValue);

// assert that the LogMe was called only once.
//  mockLogMeObj.Setup(l => l.LogMe(It.IsAny<string>()).Verify(Times.Once());
```

This gives you the best verification for the exact thing you want to verify.

am assuming Moq as the mocking framework here, but it can be whatever you're using.

Comment: raja to the rescue as always